# How to keep one rebase'd commit and un-ask for the next ones?

Tags: git, rebase

I started an interactive rebase, and picked two commits from "later in the history" to try and push them to "earlier in the history".  So I'm trying to do:

`E<-D<-C<-B<-A` => `E<-B<-A<-D<-C`

The first commit movement (B) involved merging work, but that's now done.  So it looks good and is in the right place.  But then when I did `rebase --continue` I got a ton of conflicts for A.  I realized it has a deep dependence on D that I did not notice, and I shouldn't be trying to move it this way.

But I don't want to do a `rebase --abort` because the work done on B is good.  And I don't want to `--skip` it, if that means throwing out A entirely.  :-/

How do I ask it to forget about the current wreck of an in-progress merge for A that I asked for...and act as if B was my only request?  So now I'm aiming to finish the rebase and get:

`E<-B<-D<-C<-A`

Comment: The short version is that you can't.  Rebase works by *copying* commits, not altering them, so your original `E<-D<-C<-B<-A` chain is still in there and your new `E<-B` chain-so-far is being built on a *new* branch.  Finishing the rebase abandons the old chain and moves the branch label to the new chain.  Aborting the rebase drops the new branch entirely, keeping only the old chain, so [choroba's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37417645/1256452), which adds a new name to the new-chain-so-far, is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new branch even in the middle of a rebase. Just

```
git checkout -b only-b
git rebase --abort
git checkout only-b
```

Comment: Hmmm...though what would I do after that?  I'd have merged-B and then the original chain of commits with unmerged-B still in it...both branches independent.

Comment: @HostileFork: You can now `git checkout original` and `git rebase E-commit --onto only-b-commit`.

Comment: If I replay a chain of commits for a rebase, won't it see two versions of B which will conflict with each other after the merge edits?

Comment: You can then `git rebase -i` and choose which commits to copy.  Or, you can simply `git cherry-pick` each commit in the desired order, which is what `git rebase` actually does under the covers.